# SQL to return active users that have not logged out

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server

I have been trying this the whole day but to no success. I have 3 tables in my systems which are as follows:

```
    ***User***
    UserID (PK)
    Username

   ***Usertransaction***
    UsertransactionID (PK) (auto_increment)
    UserID (FK)
    TransactionID (FK)
    TimeStamp

    ***Transaction***
    TransactionID (PK)
    TransactioName
```

[Tables and Test Data - SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8830f/1)

When a user logs into the system it get logged in the usertransaction table. 
A record with the User’s UserID, transactionID, and Timestamp is created.

This is Login : `$Query="insert into usertransaction('$UserID',1)"`
Timestamp is automatically generated by the DBMS when the record is entered.
The same is performed by the system when the user logs out but with a different transaction ID.

This is Logout : `$Query="insert into usertransaction('$UserID',2)"`

So esentially login and logout is recorded in the same database. A user can have a lot of login and a lot of logout however I want the most current once.
I have been fighting with a SQL query to return a count of all users who have logged into the system however have not logged out.
I know its Christmas but Please kindly assist.

I have this thus far:

```
select A.useriD,A.transactionID,A.Timestamp
from usertransaction
INNER JOIN 
(
    select userID, max(Timestamp) AS Latest_Login
    from usertransaction
    WHERE usertransaction=1
) AS B
ON A.UserID=B.UserID,A.transactionID=B.transactionID,A.Timestamp=B.Latest_Login
WHERE usertransaction=1


select A.useriD,A.transactionID,A.Timestamp
from usertransaction
INNER JOIN 
(
    select userID, max(Timestamp) AS Latest_Logout
    from usertransaction
    WHERE usertransaction=2
) AS B
ON A.UserID=B.UserID,A.transactionID=B.transactionID,A.Timestamp=B.Latest_Logout
WHERE usertransaction=2
```

I get the login result and logout result separately. How can I compare the two statement and check if the user is still logged in?

Comment: Hi Ryan I am trying to upload a proper word document where I have documented everything. It has screen dumps of the user tables

Comment: Here guys, here is the fiddle [link] http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8830f/1

Comment: I am trying to edit my post but I can't. Can some edit it and put the fiddle in ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Kickstart is correct although the query needs modifying:

```
SELECT ut1.UserID
    ut1.transactionID,
    ut1.Timestamp
FROM Usertransaction ut1
LEFT OUTER JOIN Usertransaction ut2
ON ut1.UserID = ut2.UserID
AND ut2.TransactionID = 2
AND ut1.TimeStamp < ut2.Timestamp
WHERE ut1.TransactionID = 1
AND ut2.UsertransactionID  IS NULL
```

Comment: Both code works however if I login and logout the query still return me. I just want to see users who have logged in and have not logged out

Comment: @Kickstart's query will always return everything as the LEFT JOIN predicate is on ut1.TransactionID being 1 AND 2 so will always output NULL. I don't see how my query can return you though if you've logged out. Can you post the data that has been written to the Usertransaction table for your login/logout?

Answer (score 1):

To get a list of the users who have a logged in record without a subsequent logged out record, join the user transactions table against itself with a LEFT OUTER JOIN and then exclude records where the log out columns are null

Something like this:-

```
SELECT ut1.UserID,
    ut1.transactionID,
    ut1.Timestamp
FROM Usertransaction ut1
LEFT OUTER JOIN Usertransaction ut2
ON ut1.UserID = ut2.UserID
AND ut2.TransactionID = 6
AND ut1.TimeStamp < ut2.Timestamp
WHERE ut2.UsertransactionID  IS NULL
AND ut1.TransactionID = 1
```

Comment: Please see above reply

Comment: Oops, typo. the 2nd check on TransactionID should have referred to ut2

Comment: I have fixed mine now. The problem was it was looking for a log out with a transaction id of 2, where with your data a logout is a 6.

Comment: It was there when you put your comment, but I have now added a missing comma.